# Perl - How to read hash data and use as hash data

Tags: perl, file, hash

I have flat data file with hash data as content. Now I want file data to be read and  can use as Perl hash with my code. The file content is like below:

I have read file content as string but I am not able to use $forum_thread_data var by reading from file content.

Please me to use it as hash data.

```
$forum_thread_data{"9"}->{"0000"} = {
    '01' => [q~A~, q~~, q~rrdude~, q~How To Sell More To USF's Prospect/Customer Base.~, 
        q~1~, q~1~, q~02-09-2012~, q~05:00 PM~, 
        q~2455967.1700~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, q~00000595~, q~rrdude~, 
        q~02-24-2012~, q~04:28 PM~, q~2455982.1628~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, 
        q~00000595~, q~1~, ],
    '02' => [q~A~, q~~, q~rrdude~, q~Dealers MUST BE PROACTIVE and REACH OUT~, 
        q~1~, q~0~, q~03-02-2012~, q~12:28 PM~, 
        q~2455989.1228~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, q~00000595~, q~rrdude~, 
        q~03-02-2012~, q~12:28 PM~, q~2455989.1228~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, 
        q~00000595~, q~1~, ],
    '03' => [q~A~, q~~, q~rrdude~, q~Don't Forget To Line-Item The USF Discount!~, 
        q~1~, q~0~, q~03-09-2012~, q~05:20 PM~, 
        q~2455996.1720~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, q~00000595~, q~rrdude~, 
        q~03-09-2012~, q~05:20 PM~, q~2455996.1720~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, 
        q~00000595~, q~1~, ],
    '04' => [q~A~, q~~, q~rrdude~, q~Fast &amp; Furious From USFoods!~, 
        q~1~, q~0~, q~03-15-2012~, q~12:12 PM~, 
        q~2456002.1212~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, q~00000595~, q~rrdude~, 
        q~03-15-2012~, q~12:12 PM~, q~2456002.1212~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, 
        q~00000595~, q~1~, ],
    '05' => [q~A~, q~~, q~rrdude~, q~RM Dealer Invited to FOUR USF Events!~, 
        q~1~, q~0~, q~03-15-2012~, q~02:12 PM~, 
        q~2456002.1412~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, q~00000595~, q~rrdude~, 
        q~03-15-2012~, q~02:12 PM~, q~2456002.1412~, q~Jerry @ ASI Home Office~, 
        q~00000595~, q~1~, ],   
};
1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the [`eval` command](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) is for. If you have that whole thing in a string, let's say `$foo`, you can do the following:

```
my %forum_thread_data;
eval $foo;
```

First you need to declare the hash. After that, you `eval` the string.

**Be aware that `eval` is dangerous**. You never know what could be in the file. If it is some bad code, you will run it.

---

If the data is in a text file with nothing else, an alternative would be to `require` or `do` the file.

With `require`, you can only load it once. Probably it's better to just use `do`, which will read and execute the file like it was code. Again, you need to declare the variable if you do not have that inside of the file.

```
my $forum_thread_data;
do 'foo.dump';
```

The same warning applies. If this is output of Data::Dumper, Data::Dump or similar from your own code, it should be save to do this. Also note that there are faster serialization formats than dumped out Perl data structures.